# Amazon API: how to get product categories from ItemLookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

How can I get item Categories from the Amazon ItemLookup operation?

For a given ItemId, I'd expect something like:

- Computers & Technology
- Programming (103)
- Content Management (27)
- Computer Science (24)
- and more as exposed  in left column here http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=drupal